# How to remove old apps from shiny-server admin screen

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

When I login to my shiny-server admin screen, and navigate to the applications tab, there is a list of every app that I have ever hosted. This is annoying to sort through and I would like to remove most of those applications, or at least not see them. How do I do this?